# Firefox 7 does fullscreen browser window

Tags: html, browser, resize, window, firefox7

I am unable to resize a browser window using javascript in Firefox 7. This code works in all the browser so far I have checked. Does anyone know why it is not working in firefox 7.

In my example I am trying to resize a window which is opened as a result of clicking a link in a parent window. Thus, I have 2 files here.

**index.html (parent)**
*Head section*

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function openwin() {
    var win1 = window.open('index2.html','mywin','left=20,top=20,width=900,height=700,toolbar=1,resizable=0');
}

</script>
```

Body section -

```
<a href="javascript:openwin()">Click to open a new window</a>
```

**index2.html (child)**
*Head section*

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function fullscreen() {
    window.moveTo(0,0)
    window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
}

</script>
```

Body section -

```
 <a href="javascript:fullscreen()">Click to fullscreen a window</a>
```

Please let me know if any help. I assume there is a bug with FF7. Many thanks

Comment: so, do you need it in a fullscreen or what? "In my example I am trying to resize a window which is opened" - resize how? where? full or specific value?

Comment: see the code. Everything is in it.

Comment: well I put your code in html on my local, and I have this: I open the index1.html  and there is a link for opening the index2.html, so I click, it is opening with the size set in javascript.. now I click on the full screen and it gets to ful screen. what is the problem. what you want to resize? 
it's working in firefox 7.0.1

Comment: Resize to any specific value. For eg. screen's height and width.

Comment: Then I am surprised that it works in FF7 ;). I checked on my and my colleague's machine. It didn't work.

Comment: yes, I changed the values for window in 100 / 100 and it's working

Comment: Possibly the fault of linux version. I will check in windows version of FF7 tomorrow and will let u know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently a bug in Firefox 7. It have been already reported to mozilla. More info available in the  [Bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=688841)

Answer (score 1):

In FF6 you should use `window.innerWidth` or `window.outerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` or `window.outerHeight` to set window size, as shown here:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Window-Browser/SettingWindowHeightandWidthFirefox.htm

Comment: Links break over time.  You should be posting the full solution as an answer.

Comment: It seems that they are blocking resizing windows(chrome,FF). It worked in FF6, but in FF7 it doesn't.